# Objective-c on linux how to start?

Tags: objective-c

Is there any objective-c ide for linux ? Where to start , how to start , any ideas ?
All good starter tutorials and links appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/) is all there is.

Answer (score 2):

Try GNUStep

http://www.gnustep.org/

Answer (score 2):

GNUstep is **NOT** an acceptable choice.  In fact it's not an IDE at all, so I presume that you're talking about projectmanager.app.  I'd prefer either gedit or Kate to that mess.  And neither of those is an IDE...but then I don't think that projectmanager.app is either.

So far I don't have a decent answer.  A highlighting text editor with a terminal window (i.e. Kate or gedit) is the best I've found.  With a makefile it's not too bad, but it sure falls way short of a decent IDE.